# AutoHotkey script for MS Excel to read a value in a specific cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, autohotkey

I need AHK script automatically to find and match a keyword in a cell then get value from the cell to the right of it and sum it to another cell. For example, cells A3 and A9 contain text "Cash", one cell to the right of each (B3 and B9) contain values `200` and `300`.

How to automatic sum it to C5?

Comment: So you want to scan the entire spreadsheet in column `A`, find the cells with `Cash`, sum the neighbor cells and put the result into `C5`? This can be done with a formula in `C5`: `=SUMIF(A:A;"Cash";B:B)`, why do you need a script for that?

Comment: Yes, you know it exactly. I am an accounting student, my teacher give us a homework to create a ledger in excel. He want us to present an example of change in debit and credit, it will time consuming if we change the value every time transaction added. 
Btw, you give me a good answer. why commenting, and not answer it directly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, added it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The simplest solution is to use a conditional formula right in Excel:

  Set `C5` cell to `=SUMIF(A:A;"Cash";B:B)`

  The formula looks at `A` column, finds cells with `Cash` text, sums the neighbor cells from `B` column and puts the result into the said `C5` cell.
- Automating Excel in AutoHotkey is possible with [ComObjActive()](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ComObjActive.htm), it's not needed in this case but you can find lots of examples by searching for `Autohotkey ComObjActive Excel example`.